# How to use Less to convert px to vw when property has multi value?

Tags: css, less

I have a mixin like this:

```
.lib-vw (@prop, @value) {
    @result: (@value / ((1440 * 0.01) * 1px)) * 1vw;
    @{prop}: @value;
    @{prop}: @result;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
div {
    .lib-vw(margin-top, 18px);
}
```

output is something like this:

```
div {
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-top: 1.25vw;
}
```

Here's [demo](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cn.lib-vw%20(%40prop%2C%20%40value)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40result%3A%20(%40value%20%2F%20((1440%20*%200.01)%20*%201px))%20*%201vw%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40%7Bprop%7D%3A%20%40value%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40%7Bprop%7D%3A%20%40result%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Cndiv%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.lib-vw(margin-top%2C%2018px)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%20%20%5Cn%20%20%2F*%5Cn%20%20.lib-vw(margin%2C%2018px%2010px)%3B%5Cn%20%20.lib-vw(margin%2C%2018px%2010px%2020px)%3B%5Cn%20%20.lib-vw(margin%2C%2018px%2010px%2020px%2030px)%3B%5Cn%20%20*%2F%22%7D)

#### Now i want `.lib-vw()` support multiple values, like this:

```
.lib-vw(margin, 18px 10px);
.lib-vw(margin, 18px 10px 20px);
.lib-vw(margin, 18px 10px 20px 30px);
```

how to update (or create new one) my mixin to support multiple values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd use something like [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/8d64084b36fc6fa0b666a3a703e65bed) by now (though `less-plugin-lists` will add support for vector/list arithmetic in next release).

Comment: Btw., `(1px / ((1 * 1) * 1)) * 1vw;` thing exposes a bug in Less as the expression should result in `px` value instead of `vw` (see http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-operations). So for future compatibility I'd suggest you to move `1vw` multiplier leftmost (or use `unit` function).

Comment: @seven-phases-max thank you so much, that what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to make mixin, which takes 4 values and combines them to one:

```
.lib-vw (@prop, @value1, @value2, @value3, @value4) {
    @result1: (@value1 / ((1440 * 0.01) * 1px)) * 1vw;
    @result2: (@value2 / ((1440 * 0.01) * 1px)) * 1vw;
    @result3: (@value3 / ((1440 * 0.01) * 1px)) * 1vw;
    @result4: (@value4 / ((1440 * 0.01) * 1px)) * 1vw;
    @result: @result1 @result2 @result3 @result4;
    @value: @value1 @value2 @value3 @value4;
    @{prop}: @value;
    @{prop}: @result;
}
div {
    .lib-vw(margin, 18px, 18px, 18px, 18px);
}
```

[Demo](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.lib-vw%20(%40prop%2C%20%40value1%2C%20%40value2%2C%20%40value3%2C%20%40value4)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40result1%3A%20(%40value1%20%2F%20((1440%20*%200.01)%20*%201px))%20*%201vw%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40result2%3A%20(%40value2%20%2F%20((1440%20*%200.01)%20*%201px))%20*%201vw%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40result3%3A%20(%40value3%20%2F%20((1440%20*%200.01)%20*%201px))%20*%201vw%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40result4%3A%20(%40value4%20%2F%20((1440%20*%200.01)%20*%201px))%20*%201vw%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40result%3A%20%40result1%20%40result2%20%40result3%20%40result4%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40value%3A%20%40value1%20%40value2%20%40value3%20%40value4%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40%7Bprop%7D%3A%20%40value%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40%7Bprop%7D%3A%20%40result%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cndiv%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.lib-vw(margin%2C%2018px%2C%2018px%2C%2018px%2C%2018px)%3B%5Cn%7D%22%7D)

Comment: `~"@{result1} @{result2} @{result3} @{result4}"` - where did you learn that way of using Less variables (it's just phew...)? Should really be just: `@result: @result1 @result2 @result3 @result4;`

Comment: @seven-phases-max Probably I forgot this to be that way when I tried to get them comma separated. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @liroP Thank you for your solution. It's very heplful for me.

Answer (score 1):

The [Lists](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less-plugin-lists#less-plugin-lists) Less plugin provides ["vector arithmetic"](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less-plugin-lists/blob/master/docs/va.md) feature. I.e. if you use the plugin your original code will work for multiple values as well:

```css
.lib-vw(@prop, @value) {
    @{prop}: @value;
    @{prop}: 1vw * @value / (1440 * 0.01);
}

div {
    .lib-vw(margin-top, 18px);
}

span {
    .lib-vw(margin, 11px 22px 33px 44px);
}
```

CSS result:

```css
div {
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-top: 1.25vw;
}
span {
    margin: 11px 22px 33px 44px;
    margin: 0.76388889vw 1.52777778vw 2.29166667vw 3.05555556vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a task of converting pixels to vw for screens > 767px, I used mixins:

```less
@sm_: ~'(min-width: 768px)';

.vw(@prop, @value) {
    @vw:round((@value*100/1726),4);
    @{prop}:1px*@value;
    @media @sm_{
        @{prop}:1vw*@vw;
    }
}

.vw2(@prop, @value1, @value2) {
    @vw1:round((@value1*100/1726),4);
    @vw2:round((@value2*100/1726),4);
    @{prop}:1px*@value1 1px*@value2;
    @media @sm_{
        @{prop}:1vw*@vw1 1vw*@vw2;
    }
}

.vw3(@prop, @value1, @value2, @value3) {
    @vw1:round((@value1*100/1726),4);
    @vw2:round((@value2*100/1726),4);
    @vw3:round((@value3*100/1726),4);
    @{prop}:1px*@value1 1px*@value2 1px*@value3;
    @media @sm_{
        @{prop}:1vw*@vw1 1vw*@vw2 1vw*@vw3;
        
    }
}

.vw4(@prop, @value1, @value2, @value3, @value4) {
    @vw1:round((@value1*100/1726),4);
    @vw2:round((@value2*100/1726),4);
    @vw3:round((@value3*100/1726),4);
    @vw4:round((@value4*100/1726),4);
    @{prop}:1px*@value1 1px*@value2 1px*@value3 1px*@value4;
    @media @sm_{
        @{prop}:1vw*@vw1 1vw*@vw2 1vw*@vw3 1vw*@vw4;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```less
.block-one{
    .vw(margin, 20);
}

.block-two{
    .vw2(margin, 20, 30);
}

.block-three{
    .vw3(margin, 20, 30, 40);
}

.block-four{
    .vw4(margin, 20, 30, 40, 50);
}
```

CSS output:

```css
.block-one {
  margin: 20px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .block-one {
    margin: 1.1587vw;
  }
}

.block-two {
  margin: 20px 30px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .block-two {
    margin: 1.1587vw 1.7381vw;
  }
}

.block-three {
  margin: 20px 30px 40px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .block-three {
    margin: 1.1587vw 1.7381vw 2.3175vw;
  }
}

.block-four {
  margin: 20px 30px 40px 50px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .block-four {
    margin: 1.1587vw 1.7381vw 2.3175vw 2.8969vw;
  }
}
```